# Ruby lazy enumerator returning different object types depending on use

Tags: ruby, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

I was attempting to solve [Project Euler #58](https://projecteuler.net/problem=58) in a functional manner with ruby.

Briefly, I created an enumerator to return the corner number of each ring.  I was then chaining functional operators on the enumerator.  When I get my result, I find that it has a different class depending on how I use it.

```
spiral = Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    n = 3
    step = 2
    loop do
        vals = n.step(nil, step).take(4)
        yielder.yield vals
        step += 2
        n = vals.last + step
    end
end

primes = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113]

levels = spiral
    .lazy
    .map { |ring| ring.count { |n| primes.include? n } }    
    .with_object({:total=>1.0, :primes=>0})
    .take_while do |ring_primes, counts|
        counts[:total] += 4
        counts[:primes] += ring_primes
        (counts[:primes] / counts[:total]) > 0.5
    end
```

The class of `levels` is a lazy enumerator.  I would expect it to contain the number of primes in each ring [3, 2, 3, etc.] - see the project euler reference.

If I just print from the enumerator, I get what I expect:

```
levels.each do |level|
    puts "#{level}"
end
```

Returns:

```
3
2
3
1
```

But if I loop `.with_index` I get an array result back where the expected value is the first member and the second is my `.with_object` parameter

```
levels.each.with_index do |level, ix|
    puts "#{ix}: #{level}"
end
```

Returns:

```
0: [3, {:total=>5.0, :primes=>3}]
1: [2, {:total=>9.0, :primes=>5}]
2: [3, {:total=>13.0, :primes=>8}]
3: [1, {:total=>17.0, :primes=>9}]
```

Why does the lazy enumerator work this way and how could I predict for it in the future?

---

#### Update

I asked around on the IRC ruby channel and no one there had any idea about it.  They said they had discussed it a day or two ago and hadn't come to any conclusions.

In general, it seems one must just deal with it and move on.

Comment: Is `*n = 3` supposed to be `n = 3`?

Comment: Yes, copy paste error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening here is you're conveniently ignoring the structure that's returned and plucking out the first item to display. In this case the first item is the `counts` structure you produce.

Have a look at this:

```
levels.each do |*level|
  puts level.inspect
end
```

That shows you what's actually in the `levels` results. When Ruby calls a lambda it will discard any additional data that doesn't fit with the number of arguments the block accepts.

If you don't need that metadata, strip it out:

```
levels = spiral
  .lazy
  .map { |ring| ring.count { |n| primes.include? n } }    
  .with_object({:total=>1.0, :primes=>0})
  .take_while do |ring_primes, counts|
    counts[:total] += 4
    counts[:primes] += ring_primes
    (counts[:primes] / counts[:total]) > 0.5
  end
  .map { |r,_| r }
```

That removes the extraneous element in the results.

Here's a way of cleaning up your Enumerator a bit:

```
class Spiral
  include Enumerable

  def each
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      n = 3
      step = 2
      loop do
        vals = n.step(nil, step).take(4)
        yielder.yield vals
        step += 2
        n = vals.last + step
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can create one with:

```
Spiral.new.each ...
```

Comment: Building on your final `.map { |r, _| r}`.  I had already done that originally, but stripped it out for purposes of this example.  However, doing `.map(&:first)` fails with "undefined method ‘first’ for Fixnum".  Again it seems like the returned datatype is rather arbitrary.

Comment: It's not that the returned datatype is arbitrary but that `map(&:first)` is equivalent to `map { |v| v.first }` which is actually `map { |v,w| v.first }` with `w` ignored, and in this case `v` is just a Fixnum. Some methods seem to check the arity of the supplied block and pass in an array, some don't. That's the difference here. The type never changes. This is one of those subtle things about how list versus array expectations can be mismatched at times.